# Запятая при деепричастном обороте (или обстоятельстве образа действия?)

Tags: пунктуация

*Хранить(,) соблюдая температурный режим* - нужна ли запятая?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, "innа" задала такой, кажущийся простым вопрос не потому, что не знает правил обособления деепричастных оборотов. Дело в том, что из этого банального правила есть исключения, причем касающиеся не только идиом. Розенталь пишет, что не обособляются деепричастные обороты (обычно со значением образа действия), тесно связанные по содержанию со сказуемым и образующие смысловой центр высказывания: Мальчик шел прихрамывая на левую ногу.
  В заданном вопросе смысл предложения не в том, чтобы "хранить", а "хранить при определенной температуре". Таким образом, запятая здесь не нужна

Comment: У Лопатина в подобном пункте уже говорится только об одиночных деепричастиях. Чем, на Ваш взгляд, "шел прихрамывая на левую ногу" у Розенталя отличается от "Он стоял, прислонясь к груде цибиков чая" у Лопатина?

Кстати, в правилах 1956 года, которые никто не отменял и на которые все-таки ориентируются все справочники, разъясняя положения "Привил..", такого пункта нет тоже. См. "Грамоту"

Comment: Может, этого пункта как раз не хватает в традиционной грамматике? Вроде бы он вполне имеет право на существование.

Comment: Да, конечно, я согласна.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, нужна. Предложение осложнено обособленным обстоятельством, выраженным деепричастным оборотом. Деепричастные обороты всегда выделяются запятыми, кроме тех случаев, когда представляют собой фразеологизм. *Работать спустя рукава.* *Работал, поглядывая на часы.*

Comment: Вообще-то еще в роли обстоятельства (обычно - образа действия) может не обособляться, если образует тесное смысловое единство со сказуемым. И не только это, ещё там есть некоторые нюансы...  
Но тут вопрос в другом. Деепричастный ли это оборот вообще.

Comment: Нюансы есть. И про частицу "И", и про про слово "который!" при обороте... Но почему Вы думаете,что это не деепричастие? Можно, конечно, сомневаться насчет запятой (что обозначает деепричастие: второе действие или нет?), но насчет части речи? "Хранить и при этом соблюдать температурный режим"

Comment: Я не про эти нюансы.
Меня здесь инфинитив основного глагола смущает. По-хорошему, деепричастие должно только к личным формам относиться.

Comment: Думаю, деепричастие "соблюдая" деепричастием и остается в данном случае. А вот что "соблюдая температурный режим" деепричастный оборот в предложении - вряд ли. Если вопрос ставим, то скорее "хранить как?" или "хранить при каком условии?", чем "хранить что делая?", хотя последний вариант тоже вроде бы приемлем. Но все же тесное смысловое единство со сказуемым здесь налицо, по-моему. И сказуемое, отделенное запятой от т. н. деепричастного оборота, выглядит как-то совсем одиноко и изолированно.

Comment: Поставьте в личную форму - и оно станет вполне себе деепричатным оборотом. "Хранил, соблюдая температурный режим". Касательно части речи. Да нехай оно деепричастием остаётся. Смысл моего высказывания не был связан с желанием подорвать основы традиционной грамматики. Может я не слишком аккуратно выразился, но меня, вроде, поняли. Речь шла о том, что деепричастие в рассматриваемом случае теряет глагольность - и, как следствие, способность образовывать деепричастный оборот.

Comment: Ок, спасибо! Кое-что выяснили. Значит, деепричастие в таких случаях может терять глагольность и, следовательно, способность образовывать деепричастный оборот, который преобразуется в обстоятельство образа действия.